# How do I make a daily challenge on a game with randomly generated levels?

Tags: encryption, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, anti-cheat

I am currently making a game with randomly made levels, but I have an interest in making everyone play the same level in a daily challenge section, like Spelunky.

At first I thought about letting the clients decide the seed based on their date, but dates can be locally spoofed.

I have access to a parse.com free account, so I can execute code in the cloud and expect results back. So then I considered asking cloud code for a hash based on the current date, but this could be spoofed to play a different level while sending the server the score for THAT level instead of the daily one.

Then I thought of encrypting the date in the server and decrypting it on the client, but then this might be problematic if I used symmetrical encryption. So... maybe use assymetrical encryption?

Am I missing a simpler solution here? This feels like I'm overcomplicating myself, but I'm not sure. Is there a generally accepted solution for this kind of problem? I haven't found anything after googling for a good while.

P.S.: I'm using unity3d, in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of basing the daily challenge by date:

- Use a mysql database to send info to the client which contains the challenge
- Process the challenge client side
- Calculate server side date and time
- Send data from the client to the server (containing score and challenge)
- Check if the challenge is still on using the server side date and time
- Submit score if the challenge is still running

One possible problem using this method is that there may be high bandwidth usage because of the extra data being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than securing the data with different encryption methods, it maybe easier to just validate the requests being sent after players finished the challenges.

- A player sends a request to start a new challenge
- server checks if this player has already completed a challenge today, proceed if it is a valid request
- challenge-related data is randomly generated on the server
- the aforementioned data is saved on the server
- send the generated data to the client
- after a certain period of time, the player sends request to server, claiming that he or she has completed the challenge
- perform verification on the data received, such as comparing the challenge ID with the one saved previously, or checking if the challenge is still available etc.
- update player account if the request is valid, ignore it otherwise

Assuming data being processed on the client side can always be hacked, it is always better to validate stuff on the server side and simplify the data encryption/decryption process on the client side for the sake of better performance of the game.